# Want to pass some parameters through the facebook auth dialog

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

In a canvas application, i want to store for which website/link come from my users.
So i want to add a parameter in my app url liek this https://apps.facebook.com/mytestapp/?source=twitter.

The application displayed a text and then when the suer click on "go to my app" he is redirected to the facebook enhanced auth dialog, if he accepted all the permissions then he is redirected to my application home page but after the auth dialog the parameter in the url have disapears.

Do you know how to pass a parameter in thee auth dialog and get it after?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way you'd get this is if the user actually appended '?source=twitter' or whatever to the URL, or by detecting the referral URL when they land on your page.

Comment: The problem is that i need to store it after the auth dialog autorisation

Comment: Then work out where the visitor is coming from when they initially land on your page, and store it in a session or cookie so you still have after they've headed to Facebook for authentication.

Comment: I agree, put the information into session serverside, or drop a cookie.